# undefined reference error while calling a function from user defined header file and it's implementation is in .cpp file

Tags: c++, c++11, codeblocks, linker-errors, header-files

What I have made is an `fstreamExtension` class that publically inherits `fstream` `class`.

**fstreamExtension.h :**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#ifndef FSTREAMEXTENSION_H
#define FSTREAMEXTENSION_H

class fstreamExtension : public std::fstream
{
 private:

    std::string fileIdentifier;

public:

    using std::fstream::fstream;
    using std::fstream::open;

    ~fstreamExtension();

    inline void fileName (std::string&);

    inline bool exists ();

    inline unsigned long long fileSize();
};
#endif
```

**fstreamExtension.cpp :**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "fstreamExtension.h"

inline void fstreamExtension::fileName (std::string& __fileIdentifier)
{
   fileIdentifier = __fileIdentifier;
}

inline bool fstreamExtension::exists ()
{
  if (FILE *file = fopen(fileIdentifier.c_str(), "r"))
  {
    fclose(file);
    return true;
  }

  else
    return false;
}


inline unsigned long long int fstreamExtension::fileSize()
{
  if(exists())
  {
    std::ifstream tempStream(fileIdentifier.c_str(), std::ios::ate |  std::ios::binary);
    unsigned long long int __size = tempStream.tellg();
    tempStream.close();
    return __size;
}

else return 0;
}

fstreamExtension::~fstreamExtension()
{
  std::fstream::close();
  std::cout << "stream closed";
}
```

When this `code` is implemented in `main` file as :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "fstreamExtension.h" 

int main()
{
  string s = "QBFdata.txt";
  fstreamExtension fs(s.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary);
  fs.fileName(s); //error
  cout << fs.fileSize(); //error
}
```

There is a `linker` `error` when I call functions `filename()` and `fileSize()`.

The `codeblocks` species the following error :

> undefined reference to fstreamExtension::fileName(std::string&)

Thanks for your help, please suggest if any structure changes are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `inline` from function declarations and definitions to fix the linker errors.

`inline` makes sense for functions defined in header files. For functions defined elsewhere `inline` makes them unavailable to other translation units, causing the linker error which you observe.

Comment: @Nilesh Not clear what you are asking. You already _have_ them.

Comment: sorry there was a typo, I was saying that it worked good, but what should I do to have them as inline, should I give them a body in header itself?

Comment: @Nilesh If you want them inline then they need to be defined in the header file.

Comment: Yeah, I did the same and it compiled.

Comment: @Nilesh Benchmark first to see if it makes sense to make them inline. These functions do not seem to be performance critical.